# docker image prune filter not working

Tags: linux, docker

> ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-191:~$ docker pull busybox Using default tag: latest
>   latest: Pulling from library/busybox 0f8c40e1270f: Pull complete 
>   Digest:
>   sha256:b91fb3b63e212bb0d3dd0461025b969705b1df565a8bd454bd5095aa7bea9221
>   Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
>   docker.io/library/busybox:latest
>
> ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-191:~$ docker image prune -a --filter "until=12h"
>   WARNING! This will remove all images without at least one container
>   associated to them. Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y Deleted
>   Images: untagged: busybox:latest untagged:
>   busybox@sha256:b91fb3b63e212bb0d3dd0461025b969705b1df565a8bd454bd5095aa7bea9221
>   deleted:
>   sha256:020584afccce44678ec82676db80f68d50ea5c766b6e9d9601f7b5fc86dfb96d
>   deleted:
>   sha256:1da8e4c8d30765bea127dc2f11a17bc723b59480f4ab5292edb00eb8eb1d96b1
>
> Total reclaimed space: 1.22MB ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-191:~$

Here as you could see I am pulling busybox image and immediately right after that I am running "docker image prune" with a filter to delete images that have been created 12 hours ago. Why does the image which I just downloaded locally (busybox:latest) gets deleted? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "created" timestamp would be when the image was built, not when it was downloaded.

When I perform `docker pull busybox` I receive a `busybox:latest` image from `docker.io/library/busybox` that was created 22 hours ago.  That would seem to fit your filter of images older than 12 hours.

Since there are no containers associated with that image, and it fits your filter, it gets deleted.